# How to update user data using django and rest framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

When trying to update a user the following message appears: "A user with this username already exists"

I have a standard Django User model and I have another profile template that extends.

How do I update this data, including the user profile.

Thank you.

Model

```
class Profile(User):
    nome_empresa = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    cnpj = models.CharField(max_length=15)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nome_empresa
```

Serializer

```
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('nome_empresa', 'cnpj')


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    profile = ProfileSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'profile')
```

View

```
class usuario(APIView):


    def patch(self, request, format=None):

        user = UserSerializer(data=request.data)

        if user.is_valid():
            user.update(instance=request.user)
            return Response(HTTP_200_OK)

        return Response(user.errors)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

django-rest-framework does not update nested serializers by default. To update the profile object, you need to override the serializer's update method.

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    profile = ProfileSerializer()

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        """Override update method because we need to update
        nested serializer for profile
        """
        if validated_data.get('profile'):
            profile_data = validated_data.get('profile')
            profile_serializer = ProfileSerializer(data=profile_data)

            if profile_serializer.is_valid():
                profile = profile_serializer.update(instance=instance.profile)
                validated_data['profile'] = profile

        return super(UserSerializer, self).update(instance, validated_data)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'profile')
```

Comment: what did you mean `place_data` is it typo?

Comment: An error has occurred: TypeError: update() missing 1 required positional argument: 'validated_data'

Comment: I was able to include the validate_data correctly, but the return is successful, nothing else is being saved in the database.